# SystemExit: 2 , args = parser.parse_args() error

Tags: python, arguments

How can I fix this ?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("mode", help="Trains or tests the CNN", nargs="*", choices=["train", "continue", "test", "confusionmatrix", "vote", "slice"])
parser.add_argument("--resume", help="The version to continue training from", required=False, default=False)
parser.add_argument("--epochs", help="The number of epochs to finish training from", type=int, required=False, default=False)

args = parser.parse_args()

print("args", args)
```

I tried

```
*args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
```

and it doesnt work

Comment: Saying "it doesnt work" is not a helpful description of the problem.  If you're getting errors, or unexpected results, show us.  Otherwise we are just guessing at what went wrong.

Comment: I think I managed to fix the problem with "
Now I get a new error due to the type of args.mode

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "and it doesnt work" - okay; **how do you try it**? **What happens** when you try that, and **how is that different** from what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't leave argument value blank. If your right value is one of them ["train", "continue", "test", "confusionmatrix", "vote", "slice"] then you have to put like this:

```
parser.add_argument("--mode", help="Trains or tests the CNN", nargs="*", required=False, default='confusionmatrix')
```

You can replace 'confusionmatrix' with any one of them ["train", "continue", "test", "confusionmatrix", "vote", "slice"]

If you get SystemExit: 2 you can try like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--mode", help="Trains or tests the CNN", nargs="*", required=False, default='confusionmatrix')
parser.add_argument("--resume", help="The version to continue training from", required=False, default=False)
parser.add_argument("--epochs", help="The number of epochs to finish training from", type=int, required=False, default=100)
parser.add_argument("-f", required=False)

args = parser.parse_args()

print("args", args)
```

You need to add in the end of " arg_parse.add_argument " line [ parser.add_argument("-f", required=False) ]

Comment: I get error in this line :                                                                                                              train_x, train_y, validation_x, validation_y =getDataset(filesPerGenreMap, genres, mode='train')                                                                                                                           the error is : '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: you need to change `parser.add_argument("--epochs", help="The number of epochs to finish training from", type=int, required=False, default=False)` to `parser.add_argument("--epochs", help="The number of epochs to finish training from", type=int, required=False, default=100)` or any number in default value. Because ( type=int ) means its value has to be any number.

Comment: I did it, I copy your code, but it still doesn't work - I get the same error

Comment: I give you an example how it works. I need to know your full code or which file you are using to find out the value you should put in your code. I predict you may need to put an version number for `parser.add_argument("--resume", help="The version to continue training from", required=False, default=False)` line, like ( default=2 ) or ( default=3 ) based on your program version.